# Facebook Canvas App Height less than 800px

Tags: facebook-apps

I have 2 facebook app one that is 872px height and another one that is 712px height. For the 827px app I have successfully re-sized the app from 800 to 872px using the facebook JS SDK. But for the 712px I haven't been able to get it down from 800px. Is there a minimum height for facebook canvas app or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Canvas APP can't go lower than 800 px.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the height dynamically? this worked for me as i am attempting to display multiple pages that are less than 800px in height. the usual height of my page tabs were ~700px.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId: window.FB_APP_ID
   });

   // set height dependent on page (min height is 800px) 
   // but we are attempting to get it shorter
   var body_height = $('body').first().outerHeight();

   FB.Canvas.setSize({ 
      height: body_height
   });
}
```

what also worked for me, if not grabbing the body height is to set the height to something shorter than any of your pages at load, then triggering the setAutoGrow() function to expand it to the proper height with some delay. though this will cause your canvas to be the initial set height (eg. 480px) then will expand to size whenever your timeout fires.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId: window.FB_APP_ID
   });

   FB.Canvas.setSize({ 
      height: 480 // some height shorter than necessary
   });

   setTimeout(function(){
      FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
   }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with it:

```
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
        function(info) {
            // console.log(info);
            if (info.clientHeight< 800) FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 800 });
        }
    );
```